# Is there some easy way to share SpaceChem save data between computers?

Tags: spacechem

While waiting for SpaceChem version 1009 or whatever to bring us the Steam Cloud, is there some easy way to share the save files and game state between computers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing extremely easy, but I know a few people have accomplished this by putting their save file into Dropbox, and then using a symlink in each computer's save folder that points to the one in Dropbox.